# Angular 5 - Router State & Form State Synchronization using NGRX Store

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, ngrx-store

### Situation

Imagine a simple application where the user has a search form and some results displayed on the same screen.

It is common practice to provide the possibility to have the search criteria reflected in the URL so that the user is able to copy & paste, go back and forth, etc.

### Challenge

To be able to provide the mentioned possibilities one needs to somehow synchronize the router sate and the form state.

- That means if the URL is pasted and the application is loaded, the parameters of the router state have to be set to the fields of the form and the search triggered right away to display the results.
- It also means if the form is submitted the parameters have to be updated and the results of the search have to be shown (remember: we have both - the form and the results - on the same page)
- One also has to take care about endless recursions here.

---

Additionally a `ngrx-store` is used to reflect the application state and consume state changes in components.

### Question

It is not clear to me on how to tie

- the router
- the form
- the store

together.

Should the search event be dispatched after navigation happened and the form submit just triggers a navigation event? Should the form consume store state updates and reflect those? The general concept is not very clear to me unfortunately.

---

So, are there recommendations, experiences, best practices I did not see? Thank you already!

Comment: I found this documentation that seems to be pretty much what you are asking for: https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-ngrx-refactoring/wiki/4.-Handling-router-state-with-@ngrx-router-store

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, if I had to implement this scenario (which I don't recommend, I would instead recommend having a search component, and a result component, but that's your call) :

- Create an url parsing service that I inject into the wanted component
- On init, parse the URL
- Trigger a behavior subject to propagate the results
- In the component, subscribe to the subject
- Create a reactive form in the constructor
- In the subscription, set the values of the form once the url is parsed. If the form isn't created yet, then create it and set the values
- Listen to changes on the form values. Everytime the form changes, the url is rewritten, [**matrix style**](https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero)
- Trigger a search event at every form value change (which can be heavy, maybe you should debounce the search)

This complies with all of your requirements :

- Launch a search at URL parse or form value change
- The URL is updated at every form value change
- No recursion

Also, I don't know why you need the store, I've enever used it and I feel fine without it. But up to you to insert it if you want !

Comment: Thank you! There is a small misunderstanding, the search should not be triggered each time the values change, but each time the user submits the form (e.g. by clicking a submit button). Same applies for changing the URL parameters. The complete application is of course more complex and consists of a whole lot more components, that's why I ended up using the store as I was passing around data using `Input()` and `Output()`.

Comment: Well then, don't listen to changes then, just to the submit event ! And about the store usefulness, even if you want to share parameters, you could just use a sharing service. But that's up to you and not relevant to your question so let's stop there with the store :)